# How to explorer temp table content when procedure debugging

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i use this statement in SQL Server 2008:

```
    --INSERT INTO #tmp_file EXEC ('restore_database_proc N''' + @database_bak_path + '''')
    INSERT INTO #tmp_file EXEC ('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N''' + @database_bak_path + '''') 
    set @database_mdf_oldname = (select LogicalName from #tmp_file where Type = 'D')
    set @database_log_oldname = (select LogicalName from #tmp_file where Type = 'L')
```

The varible  `@database_mdf_oldname` and `@database_log_oldname` have no value when i debugging the procedure,so i want to check if the temp table has value and why the result have not give the variable?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2008,have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a select statement `select * from #tmp_file` and at sql server it can be display the temp table result like this:

```
    INSERT INTO #tmp_file EXEC ('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N''' + @database_bak_path + '''') 
    select * from #tmp_file--this can be diaplay on debugging result
    set @database_mdf_oldname = (select LogicalName from #tmp_file where Type = 'D')
    set @database_log_oldname = (select LogicalName from #tmp_file where Type = 'L')
```